# amazon beanstack policy issues when running eb create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

After running 
      eb create projectname to deploy my rails project to amazon beanstack
I keep getting errors these errors. I have never used this service before and thought I would give it a try.. Here are the errors.

```
2015-10-02 17:23:50 UTC-0400    WARN    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Command failed on all instances.

2015-10-02 17:23:38 UTC-0400 ERROR Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

2015-10-02 17:22:35 UTC-0400    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].

2015-10-02 17:22:35 UTC-0400    ERROR   [Instance: i-c2e7f417] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ndeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. /var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>' Tasks: TOP => environment (See full trace by running task with --trace). Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

I am thinking it has something to do with the policys? there an easier way to set policy permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a policy error, it's an issue with your configuration. From the error you posted, this part

> (TRUNCATED)...ndeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `' Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.

indicates that your `database.yml` is misconfigured (since it defaults to SQLite) or you don't have the `sqlite3` gem installed.